# NetSuite Advanced PDF template CSS and HTML ignoring height and messing up layout when adding additional table rows

Tags: html, css, netsuite

I have the following table which is nicely laid out with the middle column being 70% of the page. However when I uncomment the first two table rows it messes up the layout with the middle column only displaying as about 50% of the page. Also the horizontal rule and "Received by:" line ignores any height and line height changes. This is part of a NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML report template.

Does any one know why?

```
            <table class="footer" style="width: 100%">
  <!-- <tr><td colspan="4" rowspan="1" style="width: 100%;"><span class="synh7recby">Received by:&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4" rowspan="1" style="width: 100%; height:1px;"><hr /></td></tr> -->
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="2" style="width: 20%;"><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${record.tranid}"/></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 70%;"><span class="synh9"><strong>BANKING DETAILS:</strong> Standard Bank, Company, Account No: 1, Branch Code: 2, SWIFT Addr: 3</span></td>
  <td align="right" rowspan="2" style="width: 10%;"><pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="1" style="width: 34%; padding: 3px 5px 0px 0px;"><span class="synh11">The debt evidenced by this account has been ceded. No set off will be recognised. No obligation has been delegated by us and any claim or dispute will remain our responsibility.</span></td>
  <td rowspan="1" style="width: 34%; padding: 3px 0px 0px 5px;"><span class="synh11">All supplies and services shall exclusively be subject to the terms and conditions. On request, we will provide you with a copy of the terms and conditions.</span></td>
  </tr></table>
```

CSS used:

```
  .synh7 {
      font-size: 10pt;
      line-height: 110%;
  }
  .synh9 {
      font-size: 8pt;
      line-height: 110%;
  }
  .synh11 {
      font-size: 7pt;
      line-height: 100%;
  }
  .synh7recby {
      font-size: 10pt;
      line-height: 70%;
  }
```

Comment: Tried in jsfiddle, but the table seemed to be 70% in both cases, could you make a fiddle where this problem exists? About `line-height`, you should apply it to the `td` element instead of `span` or replace `span` with `div`.

Comment: Unable to recreate your issue. I also tried jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm afraid it looks like this is only happening in the NetSuite template and not in jsfiddle. Will add a NetSuite tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it with:

```
            <table class="footer" style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
     <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 20%; line-height: 100%; height: 100%;"><span class="synh9">Received by:&nbsp;</span></td>
     <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 70%;">&nbsp;</td>
     <td colspan="1" style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4" rowspan="1" style="width: 100%; height:1px; line-height: 3px;"><hr /></td></tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="2" style="width: 20%;"><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${record.tranid}"/></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="width: 70%;"><span class="synh9"><strong>BANKING DETAILS:</strong> Bank, Account No: 1, Branch Code: 2, SWIFT Addr: 3</span></td>
  <td align="right" rowspan="2" style="width: 10%;"><pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="1" style="width: 34%; padding: 3px 5px 0px 0px;"><span class="synh11">The debt evidenced by this account has been ceded to the bank. No set off will be recognised. No obligation has been delegated by us and any claim or dispute will remain our responsibility.</span></td>
  <td rowspan="1" style="width: 34%; padding: 3px 0px 0px 5px;"><span class="synh11">All supplies and services of the company shall exclusively be subject to the terms and conditions on our website. On request, we will provide you with a copy of the terms and conditions.</span></td>
  </tr></table>
```